# Web_scrapping - emptry lists

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to get historical weather data from a web-page (link will be available on the code). But, it returns empty lists. I have searched, could not find the reason. I have done similar web-scraping from other web-pages & they worked. I appreciate beforehand your help. Please, try the code and see if you can understand the reason, why the code returns empty lists. I commented ends of the codes, because of the returned empty lists.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
headers = ({'User-Agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit\
            /537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36'})
year = []
date = []
time = []
maxtemp = []
mintemp = []
wind = []
years = list(range(2010, 2021, 1))
months = list(range(1, 13, 1))
urls = []
for yr in years:
    for month in months:
        base_url = "https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/germany/berlin/historic?month=" + str(month) + 
        "&year=" + str(year)
        response = get(base_url,headers=headers)
        html = response.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        year.append(soup.find_all('h1', attrs={'class': 'time'}))#[0].text.split()))
        date.append(soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'date'}))#[0].text.split(',')[1].split())
        time.append(soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'time'}))#[0].text.split())
        maxtemp.append(soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'temp low'}))#[0].text.split(':')[1])
        mintemp.append(soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'tempLow low'}))#[0].text.split(':')[1])
        wind.append(soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'wstext'}))#[0].text.split())
print(year)
print(date)
print(time)
print(maxtemp)``
print(mintemp)
print(wind)
print(len(year),len(date),len(time),len(max_temp),len(min_temp),len(date), len(wind))
```

Comment: I see info that it might be calculated from in terms of max and min within script tag containing var data = ...... but there is a copyright warning.Perhaps looks for a dedicated API?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed